# Cannot able to select on Treeview on KendoUI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, coldfusion, kendo-treeview

I need a small help on KendoUI Treeview. I am working on KendoUI Treeview Code. Here comes FactorTypes as a parent and Factors as children. So if I selected FactorType all the Factors underneath that particular FactorType will get selected. And I have All as parent node to the FactorTypes by selecting the All checkbox all the Factors in all FactorTypes will get selected.

However, I have a situation where I can able to use All checkbox and First FactorType is working fine if I use the second or subsequent FactorTypes upon selection  they are working as expected. Here are the code and screenshots.

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="event_type_id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold">
    Factor Types:
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="treeview-section" class="header k-content">
      <ul id="treeview">
        <li data-expanded="true">
          <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>
          <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" class="k-checkbox" id="select_all" />
          <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>All
          <ul class="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" id="child_treeview">
            <cfloop query="FactorTypes">
              <li id="list_treeview" data-toggle="collapse" data-expanded="true">

                <input type="checkbox" name="factor_type_id" class="k-checkbox" id="factor_type_id" />

                <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>#FactorTypes.factor_type_name#

                <cfquery dbtype="query" name="ListOfFactors">
                  select * from Factors where factor_type_code = '#FactorTypes.factor_type_code#'
                </cfquery>

                <cfloop query="ListOfFactors">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="factor_id" value="#ListOfFactors.factor_id#" class="k-checkbox" id="factor_id" />
                      <span class="k-sprite"></span>#ListOfFactors.factor_name#
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </cfloop>
              </li>
            </cfloop>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: {checkChildren: true},
        check: onCheck
    });

    // show checked node IDs on datasource change
    function onCheck() {
        var checkedNodes = [], treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"), message;

        checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
    };

    // function that gathers IDs of checked nodes
    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes){
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            if(nodes[i].checked){
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
            }

            if(nodes[i].hasChildren){
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is First FactorType Selection which is selecting all the Factors underneath the FactorType
[image: First FactorType Selection]

Whereas upon the second FactorType selection the factors are not getting selected. This is the issue. I want this to be working like the First FactorType Selection.
[image: Second FactorType Selection]

Any help is appreciated. STAY HOME STAY SAFE!

I am adding more info to the original post. Like I can modify the code to the same in the example here in this article https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

But that being said I need to get the data from the datasource which I can get through the rest services. I can do that in cfc that I need to establish parent-child relations between FactorTypes and Factors like and array. I tried that but it is not working. Here is the code for that.

```
<cfcomponent rest="true">
    <cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="mesdev.intranet.cnb"/>
    <cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"/>
    <cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />

    <cffunction name="FactorTypeTree" access="remote" returntype="string" returnformat="plain" httpmethod="GET">

        <cfinvoke component="e.qhse.sea.api.FactorType" method="FactorTypeTreeSelect" returnvariable="ftResult"></cfinvoke>

        <cfset aResults = arrayNew(1)>
        <cfloop query="ftResult">
            <cfset ftResult = structNew()>
            <cfset ftResult["factor_type_id"] = factor_type_id>
            <cfset ftResult["factor_type_name"] = factor_type_name>
            <cfset ftResult["factors"] = structNew()>
            <cfinvoke component="e.qhse.sea.api.Factor" method="FactorList" factor_type_id="#factor_type_id#" returnvariable="fResult"></cfinvoke>
            <cfloop query="fResult">
                <cfset fResult["factor_id"] = factor_id>
                <cfset fResult["factor_name"] = factor_name>
                <cfset arrayAppend(ftResult["factors"],fResult)>
            </cfloop>
            <cfset arrayAppend(aResults,ftResult)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn SerializeJSON(aResults)>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Did you tried this https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

Comment: Yes I did tried this one. Here in this they are getting the data from the datasouce. I tried the same code which worked perfectly fine. But in my case I can implement this but since I am getting the data from the database I need to get the data through rest service and can able to establish the relation between FactorTypes and Factors as a parent-child relation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks wrong:

```
<cfinvoke component="e.qhse.sea.api.Factor" 
method="FactorList" factor_type_id="#factor_type_id#" 
returnvariable="fResult">
</cfinvoke>
<cfloop query="fResult">
<cfset fResult["factor_id"] = factor_id>
<cfset fResult["factor_name"] = factor_name>
<cfset arrayAppend(ftResult["factors"],fResult)>
</cfloop>
```

The variable, `fResult`, appears to be a query object.  It's specified in the in the `query attribute` of the loop.

Using a `<cfset>` tag on a query object, as you are attempting to do, throws an error.  You can see for yourself here, https://trycf.com/gist/1b343d0997dcad33583e813afdff68b1/acf2018?theme=monokai.  Run the code.  Then uncomment either the loop or the single `cfset` command and run it again.

**Edit Starts Here**

You also have some code that looks like this:

```
<cfinvoke returnvariable = "ftResult">
<cfloop query = "ftResult">
<cfinvoke factor_type_id="#factor_type_id#" returnvariable="fResult">
<!--- fResult is also a query --->
```

Without seeing the datasource names or the sql, it's impossible to say but, you might be doing something like this:

```
<cfquery datasource = "fred" name = "q1">
select id 
from table1
</cfquery>

<cfloop query = "q1">

<cfquery datasource = "fred" name = "q2">
select id, name
from table2
where id = #id#
</cfquery>
more code
</cfloop>
```

If so, at best it's inefficient.  It can also cause other problems.  A better way is to get all your data with a single query:

```
<cfquery datasource = "fred" name = "betterQuery">
select t1.id id, name
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I tried this way which is identical to the article here.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes

I changed the HTML code which is simple div tag element.

```
<div id="treeview-section" class="header k-content">
                    <div id="treeview">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I changed the initialization of the data like this.

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataSource: [{
            id: "select_all", text: "Select All", expanded: false, items: [
            <cfoutput query="FactorTypes">
                {id: "factor_type_id#factor_type_id#", text: "#FactorTypes.factor_type_name#", expanded: false, items: [

                <cfquery dbtype="query" name="ListOfFactors">
                    select * from Factors
                    where factor_type_code = '#FactorTypes.factor_type_code#'
                </cfquery>

                <cfloop query="ListOfFactors">
                    {id: "factor_id#ListOfFactors.factor_id#", text: "#ListOfFactors.factor_name#" },
                </cfloop>
                ]},
            </cfoutput>
            ]
        }]
    });
```

This is working perfectly fine.